# Dropdown doesn't get visibile on click

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onclick

I'm very new to JavaScript. Right now i'm trying to create a simple onclick event which shows a dropdown when you click the button

Here is the [Demo](http://codepen.io/Conscious/pen/iDCFv/).

However when I click the language button the dropdown doesn't show up. I can't figure out where in the JavaScript or HTML problem lies or what i'm missing.

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: The opacity and condition is the issue. At first display will be empty so your condition does not work as you expect for the first click. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/roGBL/

Answer (score 1):

You also need to change the opacity. It's still on zero, even if you set `display` to `block`. Also note that the initial value for `style.display` won't be `"none"`, but `""`.

Comment: So If I had just removed `opacity: 0;` from the CSS code the JavaScript code should have worked fine? But because I added `opacity: 0;` to the CSS the javascript won't work unless i add `opacity: 1; to the javascript code?`

Did i understand it correctly?

Comment: @Nohman: Yes. The `opacity: 0` turns the block into transparent. If you remove the opacity from CSS, the behavior will be controlled from the `display` property only. Alternatively, you change the opacity in JavaScript to `1` via `style.opacity`.